# Quarkus security smallrye jwt

Tags: security, jwt, quarkus

I'm making a webservice in quarkus, and I want to generate tokens validate the user in my endpoints (the users are located in a JDBC). I will not use other services like keycloak. Just quarkus and my front (vuejs).

I'm trying to generate the tokens just in quarkus. How can I do it?
I'm doing something like this...

```
`@ApplicationScoped
public class JwtGen {
     public void gen() {
            String token =
               Jwt.upn("arthur") 
                 .groups(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("User"))) 
                 .sign();
            System.out.println(token);
        }
}
```

`

I created a publicKey.pem and in application.propperties, make this linemp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=publicKey.pem

Edit: My application.properties

```
    quarkus.http.cors=true
    quarkus.http.cors.origins=*
    
    
    quarkus.smallrye-jwt.enabled=true
    mp.jwt.verify.publickey=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlivFI8qB4D0y2jy0CfEqFyy46R0o7S8TKpsx5xbHKoU1VWg6QkQm+ntyIv1p4kE1sPEQO73+HY8+Bzs75XwRTYL1BmR1w8J5hmjVWjc6R2BTBGAYRPFRhor3kpM6ni2SPmNNhurEAHw7TaqszP5eUF/F9+KEBWkwVta+PZ37bwqSE4sCb1soZFrVz/UT/LF4tYpuVYt3YbqToZ3pZOZ9AX2o1GCG3xwOjkc4x0W7ezbQZdC9iftPxVHR8irOijJRRjcPDtA6vPKpzLl6CyYnsIYPd99ltwxTHjr3npfv/3Lw50bAkbT4HeLFxTx4flEoZLKO/g0bAoV2uqBhkA9xnQIDAQAB
    mp.jwt.decrypt.key.location=privateKey.pem
    mp.jwt.verify.issuer=https://example.com/issuer
```

This is the log error

```
io.smallrye.jwt.build.JwtSignatureException: SRJWT05009: 
at io.smallrye.jwt.build.impl.JwtSignatureImpl.sign(JwtSignatureImpl.java:77)
at br.com.infralog.JwtGen.gen(JwtGen.java:17)
at br.com.infralog.JwtGen_Subclass.gen$$superforward1(JwtGen_Subclass.zig:89)
at br.com.infralog.JwtGen_Subclass$$function$$6.apply(JwtGen_Subclass$$function$$6.zig:24)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
at br.com.infralog.JwtGen_Subclass.gen(JwtGen_Subclass.zig:145)
at br.com.infralog.JwtGen_ClientProxy.gen(JwtGen_ClientProxy.zig:126)
at br.com.infralog.webservice.StateWsResource.list(StateWsResource.java:58)
at br.com.infralog.webservice.StateWsResource_Subclass.list$$superforward1(StateWsResource_Subclass.zig:324)
at br.com.infralog.webservice.StateWsResource_Subclass$$function$$27.apply(StateWsResource_Subclass$$function$$27.zig:53)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
at br.com.infralog.webservice.StateWsResource_Subclass.list(StateWsResource_Subclass.zig:556)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:138)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93)
at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:481)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2442)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1476)
at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SRJWT05021: Please set a 'smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location' property
at io.smallrye.jwt.build.impl.JwtSignatureImpl.getKeyLocationFromConfig(JwtSignatureImpl.java:187)
at io.smallrye.jwt.build.impl.JwtSignatureImpl.sign(JwtSignatureImpl.java:72)
... 53 more

Please I'm in this for almost a weak... PLEASE HELPPP!!

Comment: Checkout this tutorial: https://ard333.medium.com/authentication-and-authorization-using-jwt-on-quarkus-aca1f844996a

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is in the Exception message:

> Please set a 'smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location' property

So if you did not yet set the private key in your application.properties this will most probably help you. Without it, it is impossible to generate a token.

This can be found in [the documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt#generating-a-jwt) as well:

> Note for this code to work we need the content of the RSA private key that corresponds to the public key we have in the TokenSecuredResource application.

How to configure and generate public and private keys is also described there.

Comment: this property 'smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location' is always marking as "unknown property" in application.properties. The code is not running with it. I already tried the mp.jwt.decrypt.key.location=privateKey.pem, but have 0 success

Comment: Which Quarkus version do you use? And can you post (the relevant parts of) your application.properties?

Comment: Ok, you are right and I overlooked, that smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location is deprecated and should be replaced by the one you used (mp.jwt.decrypt.key.location).
Still it is unclear, which Quarkus version you are using. That will decide about which of the properties is usable.
Can you post your maven or gradle file?